# Ng-cloak interferes with directive that measures a block dimensions

Tags: angularjs

I go straight to the code description.

**The directive** that measures height of a block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp');

// Directive to log a height. We have to add on some value to a final height, because css style will be undefined.

rootApp.directive('logHeight', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.prepMaxHeight = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.value = 0;
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.maxHeight = scope.value + scope.prepMaxHeight;
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}]);
</script>
```

**The scope value and directive applied to html div**. It gives current height of the `div`, which is applied to the same `div` as `style="max-height: {{'{{maxHeightCat}}'}}px;"`. The goal is to have precise height of a block for animation purpose.

```
<md-button ng-href="#" ng-click="showAccordion = ! showAccordion" md-no-ink>
   <span>
        Accordion button
   </span>
</md-button>

<div class="accordion-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showAccordion }" log-height style="max-height: {{maxHeight}}px;"> 
   <div class="accordion-inner-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'animate': showAccordion }"> 
       <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The problem** is flickering effect. Angular recommend `ng-cloak`, which helps, but also breaks my directive `logHeight`.

Added `ng-cloak` to the flickering block.

```
<div class="accordion-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showAccordion }" log-height style="max-height: {{maxHeight}}px;" ng-cloak> 
   <div class="accordion-inner-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'animate': showAccordion }"> 
       <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

With no `ng-cloak` declared for the `div`, it gives me needed height. With it, I get `0px`. 
`$timeout` didn't help. It may be, that `ng-cloak` directive is compiled and injected to DOM as last?

Working [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKzjOR)

Comment: I think changing CSS on `ng-cloak` to set very low opacity instead of `display: none` will fix your problem.

Comment: So have you tried getting the element height inside `$timeout` instead of before it? `ng-cloak` should be done then and element would have dimensions. Create a demo that includes your animation css. Might need a `min height` or something set also depending on animations used. `flicker` is very hard to see in code alone

Comment: @Evilzebra Opacity will just make it invisible, but div with class `accordion-wrapper` will still show up as a block with all content below shifted as low as   the `div`height is. But that wouldn't solve it anyway, because `ng-cloak` would break my directive that measures height of the `accordion-wrapper` class.

Comment: @charlietfl Have tried it, and didn't work not even calculated a height. Here is  my first time [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKzjOR)

Comment: Try to add `ng-cloak` to div `accordion-wrapper` and animation while toggling down, disappear . It's because `ng-cloak` is set to display `none` and I think it's compiled and injected to DOM as last therefore `log-height` directive measured `0px` height.

Comment: but you also have a `hidden` class that was never mentioned before either and it sets height to 0

Comment: @charlietfl I thought it didn't play a big role in my problem.

Comment: I'm not even sure in demo what the flicker problem is. No explanation in demo on what to look for. The height is being retrieved properly ..I get 97. Only issue I see is animation css doesn't show content well

Comment: It doesn't show up here, but on my local server it does. So I thought to leave `ng-cloak` and show a `class` while page loads and than kill it. That class would have `display:none` css property. It would be compiled before directive which log height.  But you excluded it.